# Where is the flaw in my algorithm for first non-repeated character?

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

I had these questions for an online coding test as part of a job interview and I was rejected the next week. I'm trying to figure out whether I did anything wrong or whether I did them right but that C# has a better way of accomplish the same tasks.

> **Q2)** Write a method to find the first non-repeating character in a string.
>
> a) To write your answer you may use any language you like. However, if your language already has libraries, you may not use those libraries.
>
> b) The strings are alphabetic characters and lower case. 
>   (For example,  "aaaabbbcccdde" -> 'e', "abcdefgh" -> 'a', "aaabbbcccddd" -> null, "aabccdeef" -> 'b')

**My answer:**

```
public char? FirstNonrepeatingChar ( String s ) 
{
    // returns the first non-repeated character in s
    // returns null if no such character exists
 for ( int j = 0, n = s.Length;  j < n ; )
   {
         int i = j;
         while ( j < n && s[j] == s[i] ) ++j;    
         if ( (j - i) == 1 ) return s[i]; // found lone character
    }
    return null; // if made it here, no such character exists
}
```

Comment: what is `last` ? When is it assigned some value?

Comment: What is the result for "aabb"?

Comment: @greybeard it returns `null`

Comment: Great. How about "aba"? (_Does_ or _should_?) "abab"?

Comment: @greybeard I think the prompt assumes that the letters are grouped

Comment: I find nits to pick (not using `///` documentation comments, naming of variables (something more telling than `i`? (which I'd pick for "outermost" integral iteration variables)), having nested loops manipulating the same iteration variable (without comment)), but the main omission for an `online coding test` may be not pointing out that `**Q2)**` doesn't pin the result for character reappearing, but not immediately (`"aba"`, `"abab"`).

Answer (score 1):

Finding the first non-repeated character is just a matter of finding a case where `string[x-1] != string[x] && string[x] != string[x+1]`. Your solution works, but can be logically simplified:

```
if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ) return null;
if( s.Length == 1 ) return s[0]; // Case 1: single-character string

if( s[0] != s[1] ) return s[0]; // Case 2: first character is different

for(int i = 1; i < s.Length - 1; i++) {

    // Main case 3: a sequence "aba" somewhere in the middle of the string
    if( s[i-1] != s[i] && s[i] != s[i+1] ) return s[i];
}

// Case 4: last character is different
if( s[ s.Length - 2 ] != s[ s.Length - 1 ] ) return s[ s.Length - 1 ];

// Case 5: Not found
return null;
```

Comment: Yours assumes that there is a `s[0]` and `s[1]`. EDIT: Just saw your edit.

Comment: @user5572578 I have added edge-case guards.

Comment: Hmmm I guess "simpler" is highly subjective

Comment: @user5572578 loops-within-loops generally look nasty, even though yours is still `O(n)`.

Comment: This does not work. `s[ s.Length ]` will generate index out of bounds

Comment: @user5572578 Did you ask your interviewer for feedback? Are you absolutely certain that it was your solution to that question specifically that caused you to fail?

Comment: @rcs sorry, typo, I forgot.

Comment: By your logic `e` in `eaaae` is non repeating.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary the question does not specify how it handles input strings with non-monotonically-changing character values.

Comment: Ah. Yes sorry my mistake. +1 ;)